# php and mysql pagination help

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I need to make a pagination like this that displays the number of data from a table in my database like this:

1 of n pages

Can anyone recommend a good tutorial for this? Thanks.

It's not a link, it just has to indicate the number of rows inside the database.

Comment: just request number of records from the database and then calculate number of pages.

Comment: Google is your friend. Search phrase: "php mysql pagination" - you'll find a lot of good tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the total number of rows during a select by adding the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS flag to your query, and following it up with a second SELECT statement:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tablename WHERE criteria='here' LIMIT 0,25;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

By knowing that you've got 25 rows on the first page (in the LIMIT), and knowing how many total rows there are, you can calculate how many pages there should be.

Comment: `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is not the best way to do that. Perform query with `count(*)` instead